# APEX create table ORA-02264 error

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, oracle-apex, create-table

```
    CREATE TABLE SubmitData
    ( sub_id NUMBER    NOT NULL,
      sub_name    VARCHAR(30)        NOT NULL,
      sub_auth   VARCHAR(30),    
     name_date    DATE    NOT NULL,
     auth_date    DATE,
     susegmentup_date DATE,
      sunameandnumber varchar(30),
      sudatecomp DATE,
      requestid    NUMBER,

      CONSTRAINT  pk_sub_id  PRIMARY KEY (sub_id),
      CONSTRAINT  fk_requestid FOREIGN KEY (requestid) REFERENCES DateRequest
    );
CREATE SEQUENCE sub_id_seq;
```

This is the query that I wrote to populate a table in the Apex application, but it gives me this error "ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint". I wrote query just like this for other tables, but all other tables were created fine except this one. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: why not change the name of those constraints? Or even better, check the user_constraints view to confirm that duplication.

Comment: My guess is you've already got a FK called fk_requestid